# Google Sign In Authentication taking long time, only loads after app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, google-signin, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app, I have implemented a Google Sign In. I am trying to get it so that when the user is authorized after pressing the google sign in button, and has signed in successfully, the user will be taken to a new tab controller. So far, this works, but only when I close the app after signing in. So basically the problem is that the user is not being taken straight to the tab bar controller.

Also, if the authorization process is supposed to take this long, or is supposed to be like this, I would like it if you could tell me how to show an activity indicator, so that the user knows that the process takes a while.

Thanks in advance!

**Here is a short video showing this:**

[Google Sign In Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZDfZNMSk5HOGlJcWFkS2RFdzg/view?usp=sharing)

**ViewController.swift code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        setupGoogleButtons()
    }

    fileprivate func setupGoogleButtons() {
        //add google sign in button
        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)
        //custom google button
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        customButton.backgroundColor = .orange
        customButton.setTitle("Custom Google Sign In", for: .normal)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomGoogleSign), for: .touchUpInside)
        customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        view.addSubview(customButton)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    }

    func handleCustomGoogleSign() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**AppDelegate code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
            print("User has been successfully signed in with Google")
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabController") as? UITabBarController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        } else {
            print("User has failed in signing in with Google")
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController") as? ViewController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        }

        return true
    }



    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
        let credentials = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
        })
    }


    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {



        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                          sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                          annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Comment: It doesn't take that long for google sign in. From your completion function, you did not do anything after user signed in successfully except a `print`. You should be doing something like show your `MainViewControoller`.

Comment: @ZacKwan Hi Zac are you talking about the func sign? I would like it if you could be a little less vague. Thanks

Comment: This part FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn

Comment: @ZacKwan Hi Zac I got it to work, by just putting the previous code into the func sign part of the AppDelegate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thats great! you are welcome =)